# Активная метка обновляется практически сразу

Tags: обсуждение, метки

*Я тут на больничном с вывихом, родные уехали отдыхать, поэтому я всех замучаю, готовьтесь :)*

Основной профиль: метки. Заметил, что информация по ним обновляется раз в сутки. Но, стоило мне случайно выбрать "Отслеживать метку по знаку" и выбрать, какую именно метку я отслеживаю, как информация именно по этой метке стала обновляться очень быстро. Что это - (выражаясь языком моих студентов) баг или фича?